# How can I add specified color to 2-d curve in 3-d plot in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I had a working code as follows:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set output "C:\\Users\\cole1\\Desktop\\gnuplot_w1.eps"
set multiplot
set isosamples 140
unset key
set title "r"
set xrange [-6:6]
set yrange [-6:6]
set zrange [-4:4]
set hidden3d nooffset
# set style arrow 1 lw 2 head filled size 0.1,20,70
unset key
# set ztics 1
set view 69,120 #Done implicitly by mousing.
# set arrow 1 nohead from 0,0,0 to 0,0,4.0 as 1 back
# set arrow 2 nohead from 0,0,0 to 0,4.5,0 as 1 back
# set arrow 3 nohead from 0,0,0 to 4.5,0,0 as 1 back
splot (x**2+y**2+1)**(0.5),-(x**2+y**2+1)**(0.5)
# set arrow 4 nohead from 0,0,2.5 to 0,0,4.0 as 1 front
unset xtics 
unset ytics 
unset ztics  
set parametric
set samples 1000
plot 0.1*sin(25*t)-1,0.1*cos(25*t)-0.5 lw 1
plot 0.06*sin(25*t)-1.25,0.06*cos(25*t)+2.75 lw 3
unset xtics 
unset ytics 
unset multiplot
```

I then tried to make the first curve appear green by changing that line (fifth-last line above) to

```
plot 0.1*sin(25*t)-1,0.1*cos(25*t)-0.5 lw 1 ; rgb "green"
```

and it gives me an `invalid command` error. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `linecolor`  command

```
plot 0.1*sin(25*t)-1,0.1*cos(25*t)-0.5 lw 1 lc rgb "green"
```